# Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':flutter:releaseApi' when trying to use Flutter with existing project

Tags: java, android, flutter

We've had Flutter successfully integrated into our existing Android project for quite some time now. However, after opening Android studio yesterday, Gradle suddenly refuses to sync and only gives me the message: `ERROR: Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':flutter:releaseApi' after it has been included in dependency resolution.`

I've integrated it following the docs on the flutter website and even tried creating a new flutter module from scratch which still doesn't work and results in the same error. When I create a brand new android studio project

I'm really at a loss here as there's nothing in my code which has changed from when it was working which leads me to believe it's an Android studio issue. I've also tried rolling back to a previous commit from a month ago which still doesn't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I really don't know how to interpret this error.

Comment: This problem has started happening to me. What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Stuck in this problem too. I solved it by **switching to channel stable.** I was in channel beta formerly, upgrade once after integration. The file "flutter.gradle" changed may be the cause. You can check out to the previous version in beta. But I think the stable channel may be better.